# Check if datetime field is 24 hours ago

Tags: php, sql

I want to know how to check a datetime field if the record is added in the last day (so max 24 hours ago). Also if the record is added 1 hour ago, 2 hours ago etc. with max 24 hours.

```
  WHERE ip = '".$ip."' AND date >= now() + INTERVAL 1 DAY"
```

I thought this was working but it isn't.
I checked Stack Overflow but all the scripts is setting the datetime to a timestamp. This can do directly in the SQL I think?

Comment: `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` with a minus sign?

Comment: DATE = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY is not working..

Comment: date >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Comment: Sorry @Fom but still not getting any results..

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Mysql. But i think i get it work.

WHERE date> NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR

Comment: Good! Both should work in the same way; "-" and "DATE_SUB()".

Answer (score 0):

```
where.... AND date >= dateadd(day, -2, getdate())
```